# citrix receiver for 14.04 lts

Tags: package-management, software-installation, dpkg

I am trying install icaclient-modified.deb and getting error.

```
Workstation@home:~/Downloads$ dpkg -b ica_temp icaclient-modified.deb
dpkg-deb: building package `icaclient' in `icaclient-modified.deb'.
Workstation@home:~/Downloads$ sudo dpkg -i icaclient-modified.deb
(Reading database ... 238986 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack icaclient-modified.deb ...
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
Unpacking icaclient (12.1.0) over (12.1.0) ...
Setting up icaclient (12.1.0) ...
dpkg: error processing package icaclient (--install):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
Processing triggers for menu (2.1.46ubuntu1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 icaclient
Workstation@home:~/Downloads$
```

Comment: A bit more detail would be of help. Where did you get the deb from? What version are you running (14.04 etc.).

Answer (score 0):

I found a work around
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2221765

It works fine but it is not integrated to the browser.
If you can download the ica launcher file (usually launch.ica) you can run with

```
./wifca.sh /path/to/launcher/launch.ica
```

You should run this in the folder where you have installed your ICAClient (in the link $home/ICAClient/linuxx86)